# Can I use easy_install?

Tags: 10.10, python

Can I use easy_install on Ubuntu 10.10? If yes, then how?

Comment: Please don't use `easy_install` if you can use `pip`, which you can consider an improved Python package manager.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

easy_install is the part of python-setuptools. First install python-setuptools

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Then you can use easy_install to install from [pypi](http://pypi.python.org)

You need to use sudo with easy_install i.e.

```
sudo easy_install module_name
```

eg: `sudo easy_install py2app`

Or there is another module python-pip which will also help in installing from pypi with command

```
sudo pip install module_name
```

eg: `sudo pip install py2app`

Comment: You bet me by 26 secs ;).

Comment: thanks a lot!   great job! I would never use 'rm' anymore!

Comment: or `apt install python3-setuptools`